# Make character look at player?

Tags: c++, math

I need to make a function that will calculate the degrees necessary to make an NPC look at the center of the player. However, I have not been able to find any results regarding 3 dimensions which is what I need. Only 2 dimensional equations. I'm programming in C++.

Info:

Data Type: Float.

Vertical-Axis: 90 is looking straight up, -90 is looking straight down and 0 is looking straight ahead.

Horizontal-Axis: Positive value between 0 and 360, North is 0, East is 90, South 180, West 270.

Comment: What are the inputs to this function?

Comment: @SisterFister Player xyz coordinates and NPC xyz coordinates. An array of 3 floats for player coordinates and an array of 3 floats for NPC coordinates.

Comment: `sin theta = dz/sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)` where `dx` is player's `x` minus NPC's `x`  (and similarly `dy` and `dz`). That's basic school trig.

Comment: @SisterFister That won't really work correctly. Spherical coordinates are not simply a generalization of polar coordinates.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This does not work for y. I know how to get x-degrees because it's 0 to 360. But because y-degrees is -90 to 90 it doesn't work the same.

Comment: Actually, my formula is wrong. The correct one is `tan theta = dz/sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)`. Arctangent would give you precisely -90 to 90 range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [these transformation equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) from Wikipedia.  But note since you want "elevation" or "vertical-axis" to be zero on the xy-plane, you need to make the changes noted after "if theta measures elevation from the reference plane instead of inclination from the zenith".

First, find a vector from the NPC to the player to get the values `x, y, z`, where `x` is positive to the East, `y` is positive to the North, and `z` is positive upward.

Then you have:

```
float r = sqrtf(x*x+y*y+z*z);
float theta = asinf(z/r);
float phi = atan2f(x,y);
```

Or you might get better precision from replacing the first declaration with

```
float r = hypotf(hypotf(x,y), z);
```

Note `acosf` and `atan2f` return radians, not degrees.  If you need degrees, start with:

```
theta *= 180./M_PI;
```

and `theta` is now your "vertical axis" angle.

Also, Wikipedia's `phi = arctan(y/x)` assumes an azimuth of zero at the positive x-axis and pi/2 at the positive y-axis.  Since you want an azimuth of zero at the North direction and 90 at the East direction, I've switched to `atan2f(x,y)` (instead of the more common `atan2f(y,x)`).  Also, `atan2f` returns a value from -pi to pi inclusive, but you want strictly positive values.  So:

```
if (phi < 0) {
    phi += 2*M_PI;
}
phi *= 180./M_PI;
```

and now `phi` is your desired "horizontal-axis" angle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with math which involves rotation and 3d envionments, but couldn't you draw a line from your coordinates to the NPC's coordinates or vise versa and have a function approximate the proper rotation to that line until within a range of accepted +/-? This way it does this is by just increasing and decreasing the vertical and horizontal values until it falls into the range, it's just a matter of what causes to increase or decrease first and you could determine that based on the position state of the NPC. But I feel like this is the really lame way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

use [4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) instead of Euler angles for this. You create the matrix anyway so why not use it ...

1. **create/use NPC transform matrix `M`**

   my bet is you got it somewhere near your mesh and you are using it for rendering. In case you use Euler angles you are doing a set of rotations and translation and the result is the `M`.
2. **convert players GCS Cartesian position to NPC LCS Cartesian position**

   **GCS** means global coordinate system and **LCS** means local coordinate system. So is the position is **3D** vector `xyz = (x,y,z,1)` the transformed position would be one of these (depending on conventions you use)

   ```
   xyz'=M*xyz
   xyz'=Inverse(M)*xyz
   xyz'=Transpose(xyz*M)
   xyz'=Transpose(xyz*Inverse(M))
   ```
3. **either rotate by angle or construct new NPC matrix**

   You know your **NPC**'s old coordinate system so you can extract `X,Y,Z,O` vectors from it. And now you just set the axis that is your viewing direction (usually `-Z`) to direction to player. That is easy

   ```
   -Z = normalize( xyz' - (0,0,0) )
    Z = -xyz' / |xyz'|
   ```

   Now just exploit cross product and make the other axises perpendicular to Z again so:

   ```
   X = cross(Y,Z)
   Y = cross(Z,X)
   ```

   And feed the vectors back to your **NPC**'s matrix. This way is also much much easier to move the objects. Also to lock the side rotation you can set one of the vectors to `Up` prior to this.

   If you still want to compute the rotation then it is:

   ```
   ang = acos(dot(Z,-xyz')/(|Z|*|xyz'|))
   axis = cross(Z,-xyz')
   ```

   but to convert that into Euler angles is another story ...

With transform matrices you can easily make cool stuff like camera follow, easy computation between objects coordinate systems, easy physics motion simulations and much more.